# Using struct and point to input and output info

Tags: c++, c

I have a problem with inputting a string pointer in struct. This is my code:

```
typedef struct{
        char *name;
        int age;      
}stu;

void allocate(stu* &s, int n){
     s = (stu*) malloc(n * sizeof(stu));
     if(s == NULL){
          printf("\nNot enought memory!");
          exit(1);
     }     
}
// Input info
void input_info(stu* &s, int n){
     void input(stu &s); //prototype
     for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
             printf("\n-- Student #%d:", i+1);
             input(*(s+i));
     }    
}

void input(stu &s){
     fflush(stdin);
     printf("\nEnter student's name: ");
     gets(s.name);
     printf("\nEnter student's age: ");
     scanf("%d", &s.age);
}
// End input

//Output info
void output_info(stu* s, int n){
     void output(stu s); //prototype
     for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
             printf("\n-- Student #%d:", i+1);
             output(*(s+i));
     }
}

void output(stu s){
     printf("\nName: %s", s.name);
     printf("\nAge: %d", s.age);
}
//End output

int main(){
    stu* s;
    int n;
    printf("How many students you want to input?: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    allocate(s, n);
    input_info(s, n);
    output_info(s, n);
    getch();
}
```

When I input second student's name, it's breaked? I allocated memory. And I want to ask how to deallocate memory for stu pointer? Thanks for reading

Comment: [Read a book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), because this is not proper C++ code. Use std::string, don't ever touch malloc, remove all pointers and dynamic allocation, don't use stdio.

Comment: You should allocate for `name`

Comment: Adding salt into that wound.. `fflush(stdin);` is undefined by the standard.

Comment: As Cat Plus Plus said, your code is very unidiomatic. Are you trying to write C++ code or C code ? It looks like C code but with a few C++ features mixed in. The solution won't be the same depending on your goal.

Comment: The oddest part to me is amongst this chaos he actually uses a reference-to-pointer parameter *correctly* (albeit his stock immediately goes down with the ensuing `malloc()`). I know professional engineers that struggle with that concept, and he just walks up and tags it =P

Comment: See that `gets()`? That thing is so evil its deprecated and won't  e in the next version of the language. Think about what it is doing, where it is *putting* the data it is supposedly getting, and how you can avoid that mess by using `std::string`, `std::getline()` and throwing out that `malloc()` in favor of `new`.

Comment: @WhozCraig Moreover, it's the only C++ feature in this code :)

Comment: Oh, I sorry. I code it with C but I coded it with a few C++ >"<! @WhozCraig

Answer (score 4):

There are many things that can and should be improved in your program. Some suggestions:

1. Remove the `char *` member replace it with `std::string`. [You don't want to do manual memory management for anything unless you really want to.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022117/why-should-one-use-stdstring-over-c-style-strings-in-c)
2. Drop the silly `scanf` and `printf`, they are not *type safe*. [Since you are using C++ use `std::cin` and `std::cout` and you are much safer than usage with later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780072/when-to-use-printf-scanf-vs-cout-cin).
3. Drop the `fflush(stdin)`, Calling `fflush` on anything other than `stdout` [gives you undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810410/alternative-for-fflushstdin).
4. In C++, You would usually want to use `new` and not `malloc`. [Avoid using dynamic memory allocation at all, if you can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-new-be-used-as-little-as-possible). Prefer to use a `std::vector` instead.

---

**[Online Sample](http://ideone.com/VEaQLa)**:
Following the above suggestions your example can be written as:

```
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>

typedef struct
{
    std::string name;
    int age;      
}student;

// Input info
void input_info(std::vector<student> &s)
{ 
    student obj;
    std::cout<<"\nEnter Students name";
    std::cin>>obj.name;
    std::cout<<"\nEnter Students age";
    std::cin>>obj.age;
    s.push_back(obj);
}

// Output info
void output_info(const std::vector<student> &s)
{
    for (auto itr = s.cbegin(); itr != s.cend(); ++itr)
    {
        std::cout<<"\nName:"<< itr->name;
        std::cout<<"\nAge:"<< itr->age;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cout<<"How many students you want to input?\n";
    std::cin>>n;
    std::vector<student>s;
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        input_info(s);
    }
    output_info(s);
    return 0;        
}
```

Comment: Also, as @BLUEPIXY points out, no space has been allocated for `name`, so writing to it is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Beta: `#1` takes care of it.

Comment: Yes, but it's an important error to point out for pedagogy, if only to drive #1 home.

Answer (score 0):

As some of the previous poster have mentioned, the code is not "pure" c++, as it mixes a lot of C and C++ features. Personally I think it is a less problematic when dealing with POD structs, like yours.

The crash is likely caused by gets(). It assumes that the char pointer is already allocated with a suitable capacity. It has undefined behavior when the inputs strings is longer than the capacity. Your capacity is 0, hence the crash.

If you insist on using C functions, see: [Safe Alternative to gets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309746/safe-alternative-to-gets).
Otherwise lookup getline().